Book: 80's/90's Novel About Animals/Magic Shapes/Dreams
I'm looking for a book I read in the early/mid 1990s.
All I can remember is it focused on a girl who was maybe stuck in a dream? To leave the dream, she had to learn to cast four magical shapes.
Each shape was taught to her by an animal. I'm fairly certain one was a goldfish, and one was some kind of bird like a heron/stork.
The cover had geometric shapes and a goldfish.

Do you recall what sort of time period/society the story was set in?

It was "modern day", in the 90s, anyways. Maybe the girls family was Chinese? But I don't remember.
